# how-to-display-a-message-when-clicking-on-a-submit-button-in-html

Tags: html, submit, alert, message

I have a submit button in my form. When i click on the button,it should pass a message. which method should i use? I have tried` many codes but no result. can someone help me out

```html
<button ondblclick="myalert()">
    submit
</button>

<script>
    function myalert() {
        alert("order is confirmed");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use onclick instead of ondblclick, or just double click your button

Comment: ca i add a button inside the message box

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the click event method from `ondblclick` to `onclick`.

so when you click on the submit button it will open a alert box

Comment: how to add a 'return home' button in the messagewbox